# How to set the size of a webview window in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm a beginner in `Swift` programming and would like to add a `webView` to my app, but I can not set the size of this `view` properly. The goal was to place this `webView` in the lower third of the screen (portrait mode), therefore I tried the `webView` window in the `storyboard` to look like that and set the constraints.

For programming the `webView` I oriented myself on the apple dev guide: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

The Problem is, that every time I launch the app, the `webView` just appears in fullscreen instead of the modelled area in the `storyboard`.

I thought maybe I can modify the line with

`webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)`.

I tried to create custom frames, but nothing worked for me, just fullscreen.

Can someone tell me how to setup the `webView` window with the bounds from the `storyboard`?

Should I also use the `WKWindowFeatures` class?

I really searched for hours and watched a lot of youtube-videos for this, nothing helped me. I really appreciate any help, thank you.

UPDATE/Solution:

Thanks to everyone in the comments! Everyone helped me a lot! I tired out the different solutions, some worked from the beginning, others with some further research. I was running into beginner errors like `Couldn’t instantiate class named WKWebView` or `This Class is not Key Value Coding-Compliant for the Key`. The first one I solved with checking the constraints and the second one with adding the WebKit Framework in the Build phase Tab in General. 
The solution from @AshishGupta worked for me the best. 
[solutionscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNJkX.png)

Comment: In your question, could you post a screen shot of your storyboard and the constraints you have set please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the following code for simple `webView`: The image will show the small `webView`.**

[image: Look at the below image]

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var wkwebView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.apple.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        wkwebView.load(myRequest)    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to StackOverflow and iOS.

You're not wrong in your approaches. Both setting constraints right and setting custom frames should work out fine. However there is very minute detail in the Apple developer documentation that could be messing with everything.

There is this line `view = webView` at the end of the function `override func loadView()`.

This discards everything that has been done to the UIViewController's View property till that point, and sets it to the webView object.

Removing that line should fix all of your problems. If it doesn't, please update your question with a screenshot of your storyboard constraints for the webView.

You should also move your webview set up outside the `loadView()` function. Probably to `viewDidLoad()` or to `viewWillAppear`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a `WKWebView` as a `subview` to make it resizeable.

```
    var webView: WKWebView!
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height-500, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 500), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())

        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://developer.apple.com/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
        
    }
```

That code makes something like this:

[image: webview loading on bottom half of phone]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### **1. WKWebView Using Constraints**

Assuming that you want fix height to the webView, You can set constraint programatically like this

simply take WebKit View from storyBoard and create outlet of ur WebView

```
 @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
```

then set constraint to webView like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -30)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -30)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 350)
    view.addConstraints([trailingConstraint, leadingConstraint, bottomConstraint, heightConstraint])

//Leading = 30 from superview
//Trailing = 30 from superview
//Bottom = 30 from superview
//Equal height = 350

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)

}
```

---

### 2. WKWebView Without Constraints

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-330, width: self.view.frame.width-60, height: 300))

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
        view.addSubview(webView)
   }
```

---

[image]